# Facing Issues when working with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to create an application in which I have to work with Fragment.
In the MainActivity, there is a webView. From the SecondActivity I
have starting using Fragment.

Here is the code of SecondActivity:

```
package com.dev.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Second extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);


    }

    public void choosefragment(View view) {

      Fragment fg;

        if(view == findViewById(R.id.secondbtn2)) {

            fg = new SecondFragment();
        }

        else
        {
            fg = new FirstFragment();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag1, fg);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Hhere is its **second.xml** file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

   <Button
     android:id="@+id/secondbtn1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="first fragment"
     android:onClick="chooseFragment" />

   <Button
     android:id="@+id/secondbtn2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="second fragment" 
     android:onClick="chooseFragment"/> 

   <fragment 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:name="com.dev.testapp.fragment1"
       android:id="@+id/frag1"
       />
 </LinearLayout>
```

After that I created two more classes for Fragments as it is required 
code of FirstFragment:

```
    package com.dev.testapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{


        public View onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             //Inflate the layout for this fragment

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);

        }

    }
```

And here is the SecondFragment:

```
    package com.dev.testapp;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class SecondFragment extends Fragment{

        public View onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             //Inflate the layout for this fragment

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container, false);

        }

    }
```

When I am done with all this, my SecondActivity is showing an error that I don't know how to handle:

[image: screen shot of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in previous answers, your problem is incorrect Fragment library for FirstFragment.

Change line 5 of FirstFragment.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

to:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: hey Shaun, I need to ask you one more thing buddy.  after fixing this issue.. I am trying to run to my application it is giving me an error that is : **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo(com.dev.testapp/com.dev.testapp.firstFragment):java.lang.classCastException:com.dev.testapp.FirstFragment cannot be cast to android.app.activity**

Comment: I'm not sure without more information, but it looks like you might be trying to launch a Fragment as an activity? Have you included the Fragment in your Manifest by mistake?

Comment: Actually I am using Second.java as an activity only and mentioned this in manifest.xml file.. do I need to remove that from that??

Answer (score 1):

your activity use this `import android.app.Fragment;`

your fragment is `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

So you either have both extending the Fragment in the app package or in the support library

Answer (score 1):

Your second fragment is of the type android.app.Fragment while your first fragment is android.support.v4.app.Fragment.